# Spring Mongodb findandModify fails to update entire document

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am new to mongodb and struggling to understand how document update works.
I have a document called 'menu':

```
{
 "someId":"id123",
 "someProperty":"property123",
 "list" : [{
    "innerProperty":"property423"
 }]
}
```

which maps to my entity:

```
@Document(collection = "menu")
public class Menu {
 @Id
 private String id;
 private String someid;
 private String someProperty;
 private List<SomeClass> list;

 // accessors
}
```

when I try to find and update this document like this it does not update the document. It sure does find the menu as as it returns the original entity with Id:

```
@Override
public Menu update(Menu menu) {
    Query query = new Query(
            Criteria.where("someId").is(menu.getSomeId()));
    Update update = Update.update("menu", menu);
    return mongoOperations.findAndModify(query, update,
            FindAndModifyOptions.options().returnNew(true), Menu.class);
}
```

But if I change it to this, it works:

```
@Override
public Menu update(Menu menu) {
    Query query = new Query(
            Criteria.where("someId").is(menu.getSomeId()));
    Update update = new Update().set("someProperty", menu.getSomeProperty())
     .set("list", menu.getList());
    return mongoOperations.findAndModify(query, update,
            FindAndModifyOptions.options().returnNew(true), Menu.class);
}
```

I don't really like this second method where each element of the document is individually set, as you might imagine I have a rather large document and is prone to errors.

Why does the first method not work? And what could be a better approach to update the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the docs for [findAndModify](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#findAndModify-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update-java.lang.Class-) - it returns the version of the document **before** the fields were modified. If you do a new `find()` straight after, you will see that your changes were actually saved to MongoDB.

Comment: or, if u want to save an extra db call, u can pass   [[ new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true) ]] as one of the arguments.that will return the new document instead of the old one